# git-tfs local Git repo to TFVC

Tags: git, github, tfvc, git-tfs

I'm testing out git-tfs with an on-premises TFS instance (does it work with VSO, too?) and trying to use `rcheckin` to push my Git commits up to TFVC. However, when I try and use `rcheckin`, I get an error that no TFS parents are found. The TFVC repo I'm pushing to is empty, and I want to push my changes from Git to TFVC. Here's what I've done:

```
C:\git add remote tfs http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject
C:\git tfs rcheckin -master
Working with tfs remote: default
No TFS parents found!
```

What am I missing? Do I run this command for my other branches (like feature1, feature2, etc.)? I'm pretty new to Git-TFS, but it seems like a very handy tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer : I'm one of the developer of git-tfs...

> does it work with VSO, too?

Yes!

> What am I missing?

Before being able to work with git-tfs (and use the `rcheckin` command), you MUST [clone](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md) your tfs repository.

Feel free to read the other docs, too. 
The use of rcheckin is a good idea ;-)

> How do I use an existing Git repo (separate) to push changes to the TFS repo? I've cloned the TFS repo, and it looks like it goes into a separate folder with it's own .git folder

Git-tfs is not intended to do that. But a (difficult!) solution exists using `rebase`.

1. Add your existing repo as remote in the new repo cloned from TFS and fetch
2. Use `git rebase --into` to rebase your old existing commits into the one fetched from tfs
3. Use `rcheckin` to push the commits
4. Do that again and again if you have branches (with more subtilities. I hope you have not!!!)

edit: I have [written a shell script](https://gist.github.com/pmiossec/2421ffcc8011e873641b) to replace the first 2 steps and make it easier and quicker.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! How do I use an existing Git repo (separate) to push changes to the TFS repo? I've cloned the TFS repo, and it looks like it goes into a separate folder with it's own .git folder.

Comment: Git-tfs is not intended to do that. But a (difficult!) solution exists using `rebase`.
1. Add your existing repo as remote in the new repo cloned from TFS and fetch
2. Use `git rebase --into` to rebase your old existing commits into the one fetched from tfs
3. Use `rcheckin` to push the commits
4. Do that again and again if you have branches (with more subtilities. I hope you have not!!!)

Comment: Perfect, great answer! Luckily, didn't have to go this route, but now I know! :)

Comment: Makes sense to do it like this. Would be nice to have this as an 'git-tfs add-tfs' command, that basically does what the clone command does except that it doesn't do the git stuff. ;)

Comment: Regarding a separate GIT repo (repoA) and how to push changes from it to TFS - what I ended up doing was cloning the TFS repo to a GIT repo (repoB) using git-tfs, then merging changes from repoA to repoB (locally) and commiting them from repoB to TFS. The script described here did not work for me.